# How can I add a new cookie to chrome using powershell

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell, cookies

How do I add a new cookie to chrome using powershell

I searched for this topic and couldn't find anyone talking about it before

Comment: What kind of cookie? For which website? What's the goal? Please add more details.

Comment: I need this for my project which is supposed to request a page from my site temporarily through cookies (my site requires login)

Comment: The website creating the page should be able to issue a cookie (which is much like what I suggested in my answer).

Comment: Why not just log in with your project then? Why is setting up a cookie with PowerShell the way to go?

Comment: I'll keep it short. I want to put cookie data on client devices (the program opens Chrome browser full screen and embeds it in my site) I'm not stealing anything!!

Comment: so it sounds like certificate authentication would be a better approach for your usecase. just install the cert when you install the product, and voila.

Comment: Please note, comments aren't intended for discussion but for others to ask for clarifications, make suggestions that don't qualify as a full answer. So instead of answering in comments rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778504/edit) your original question to add new info, clarifications etc. to keep everything relevant readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are only added by the website wanting add a cookie to your cookie management App.

You do not create proper working cookies unless you host a website that would do this. Cookie content is very often personal and encrypted so we can manage websites easily.

Comment: While researching this topic, I saw powershell scripts that decrypt chrome cookies file.

Is there no way to complete the rest and add a new cookie to chrome cookies file?

Comment: I have not seen any way for any individually add one's own cookie to the the chrome file. Cookies identify me and some personal (encrypted) info about me to the website.

Comment: I know this is pretty much impossible, but I'm waiting maybe some geniuses can help me out of this predicament

Comment: What *"predicament"* are you referring to?